# extension Date { has no effect

Tags: ios

This is my original timestamp code
How should I modify to cite him
How should I modify the code to refer to the "extension Date {" code

```
 func getDatas(){ 
if let timestamp = document.get("timestamp") as? TimeInterval {
                                        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)
                                        let post = Post(email: email, caption: caption, imageUrl: imageURL, date: date)

...

...

...




func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell
        let post = self.postArray[indexPath.row]
        let date = post.date
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        
        self.getUserInfo(userEmail: postArray[indexPath.row].email,cell: cell)
        cell.captionLabel.text =  postArray[indexPath.row].caption
        cell.postImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: postArray[indexPath.row].imageUrl))
        
        cell.timeLabel.text = dateString
```

I want to change to the following date display method, but the changes have no effect

```
extension Date {
   
    static func timeString(timeInterval: TimeInterval) -> String{
      
        let date = getNowDateFromatAnDate(Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval/1000))
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        if date.isToday() {
            //是今天
            formatter.dateFormat = "今天HH:mm"
            return formatter.string(from: date)
            
        }else if date.isYesterday(){
            //是昨天
            formatter.dateFormat = "昨天HH:mm"
            return formatter.string(from: date)
        }else if date.isSameWeek(){
            //是同一周
            let week = date.weekdayStringFromDate()
            formatter.dateFormat = "\(week)HH:mm"
            return formatter.string(from: date)
        }else{
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
            return formatter.string(from: date)
        }
    }
...
...
...
...
```

How should I modify to cite him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **static** keyword allow us to attach the method to a **class/struct** rather than to instances of it.
And since the `static func timeString(timeInterval: TimeInterval) -> String` in your **Date** extension returns a string you can replace your **Post** `date: Date` variable with `timeString: String` and then you can access it directly:

```
if let timestamp = document.get("timestamp") as? TimeInterval {
  let timeString = Date.timeString(timeInterval: timestamp)
  let post = Post(email: email, caption: caption, imageUrl: imageURL, timeString: timeString)
  // ...
}

cell.timeLabel.text = post.timeString
```

Comment: Happy yo help :)